# iOS Make a phone call and pass data

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, xcode7

For a Proof of Concept, I'd like to be able to make a phone call to a specific phone number and pass data to the telephone number.

Is this possible?

Comment: pass data to telephone number ? what does that mean

Comment: You can make call to one specified phone number.

Comment: you can make calls as suggested already but what do you mean by passing data?

Comment: I want to pass data from the app along with my phone call, so that the person picking up the phone knows about what subject I called.

I mean this without looking at the other end of the line, but just the part of calling someone and sending the topic about which the person is calling.

Comment: This is utterly impossible on every level. The GSM network does not allow this, neither does iOS

Answer (score 3):

for your first question `I'd like to be able to make a phone call to a specific phone number`

**Ans:**

**YES**, you can do it like

for ex

```
 let phoneNumber = "1234567890"

    if let phoneCallURL = NSURL(string: "telprompt://(phoneNumber)") {
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        if application.canOpenURL(phoneCallURL) {
            application.openURL(phoneCallURL)
        }
        else{
            println("failed")
        }
    }
```

for your second question `pass data to the telephone number`,

**Ans:**

**NO, it is not possible**

> but, you can send the data to backend on that call event, and trigger the sms to particular number